# How to print in algorithmic package for some If condition or For loop in one line?

Tags: line-breaking, algorithms

How to print

```
\FOR{$j:=0,\ldots,i-1$} 
         \STATE{$\C_{ij}:=\C_{ii}\cdot\C_{ij}$};
         \ENDFOR
```

in one line instead of two line?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please always add a full, but [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 7):

You should define your own command for placing algorithmic content on a single line. As a suggestion, consider:

```
\newcommand{\LINEFOR}[2]{%
    \STATE\algorithmicfor\ {#1}\ \algorithmicdo\ {#2} \algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor%
}
```

which prints the regular `algorithmic` package keywords used in the construction of a for statement (`\algorithmicfor`, `\algorithmicdo`, etc.), but does all of this in a single `\STATE` statement (or line).

Here is a complete minimal example illustrating the result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}%
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\LINEFOR}[2]{%
    \STATE\algorithmicfor\ {#1}\ \algorithmicdo\ {#2} \algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor%
}

\begin{algorithmic}
    \STATE \ldots
    \FOR{$j:=0,\ldots,i-1$}%
        \STATE $\mathcal{C}_{ij}:=\mathcal{C}_{ii}\cdot\mathcal{C}_{ij}$;%
        \ENDFOR%
    \STATE \ldots
    \LINEFOR{$j:=0,\ldots,i-1$}{$\mathcal{C}_{ij}:=\mathcal{C}_{ii}\cdot\mathcal{C}_{ij}$}%
    \STATE \ldots
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A version that makes an `if` one one line: `newcommand{\LineIf}[2]{
    \State \algorithmicif\ {#1}\ \algorithmicthen\ {#2} \algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif
}`