# How to make "for all xxx do" appear on one line?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

This is an example

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,setspace,hyperref}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in,right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm*}[t]                                                           
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \FORALL{$i \in S$}
            \STATE{Do something}
        \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

Result is:
[image]

However I want to have only one line "for all i \in S do Do something".
How to make it?

Comment: Would this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22780/34618

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a definition consistent with the `algorithmic` package:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\LINEFORALL}[3][default]{%
  \ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ #2\ \algorithmicdo%
  \ALC@com{#1}\ #3\ \algorithmicendfor%
}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,setspace,hyperref}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in,right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\LINEFORALL}[3][default]{%
  \ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ #2\ \algorithmicdo%
  \ALC@com{#1}\ #3\ \algorithmicendfor%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm*}[t]
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \LINEFORALL{$i \in S$}{Do something}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you, instead, want "end for" in a new line, change its definition as follows

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\LINEFORALL}[3][default]{%
  \ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ #2\ \algorithmicdo%
  \ALC@com{#1}\ #3\ALC@it\algorithmicendfor%
}
\makeatother
```

and you'll have

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you want to get rid of "end for", beware that you can not use `\ENDFOR` to close the "for all" inline statement. In this case it's better to define also a new command `\LINEENDFOR`. In other words, use the following definitions

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\LINEFORALL}[3][default]{%
  \ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ #2\ \algorithmicdo%
  \ALC@com{#1}\ #3%
}
\newcommand{\LINEENDFOR}{\ALC@it\algorithmicendfor}
\makeatother
```

and then you can use simply

```
\LINEFORALL{$i \in S$}{Do something}
```

if you don't want to close the "for all" statement,

```
\LINEFORALL{$i \in S$}{Do something}
\LINEENDFOR
```

otherwise.

Comment: What if I want to get rid of "end for"? I need just delete \algorithmicendfor from command definition?

Comment: @msh See the edit.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm*}[t]                                                           
   ~\strut\scriptsize1: 
   \algorithmicforall{}  $i \in S$  \algorithmicdo{}        
   Do something 
   \algorithmicendfor
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to use the predefined definition for the line number.